# Display category overview of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

Dear Stackoverflow community

I have a wordpress site with categories and also a custom post type.

Now i want to list all custom post type posts from a spcific category on a site.

With normal posts it is working, and all the posts it the category archive are listed on the site url/custom-post-type-slug/category-slug

But now I want that also the post from the custom post type get listed.

How can I include them in the category archive?

Kind Regards
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

When you register your custom post type. You can add a parameter has_archive to include them into archives.

Example:

```
  register_post_type( 'custom',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Cryptomonnaie' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Cryptomonnaie' )
      ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    )
  );
```

If the has_archive parameter is already set. You can try to add a filter to your functions.php file to alter query for category and tags this way:

```
   add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
 if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type)
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = array('post','photo', 'geek', 'sport', 'bio', 'news','tv', 'trends', 'societe'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
        return $query;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
By adding your function it is working, but unfortunately the navigation disappeared.
Lukas

Comment: The navigation? What do you mean?

Comment: In  my themes header.php file there is written <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?> but on the category archive this menu disappears copletely. Only the html around stays. On all other pages the menu is visible.

Please check out: https://spielraum-maybaum.ch/produktgruppen/zwergenwelt/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CPT UI to create custom post type there is an option "**Has Archive**". Set it to True.

Otherwise

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code made it:

```
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type( $query ) {
  if( is_category() &&  $query->is_main_query() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'replace_with_custom_post_type'));
      return $query;
    }
}
```